# Issue while deleting the file : Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

```
$path = public_path(). '/Images/';
$this->MakeDirectory($path);

$this->DeleteOldProfileImage($path. \Auth::guard("api")->user()->ProfileImage);
```

When i printed the url: It is like below: C:\xampp\htdocs\My\Learning\admin/public/Images/ajax-loader.gif

as below code on localhost, file does not exists.

```
private function DeleteOldProfileImage($filePath) {
    if (\File::exists($filePath))
    {      
        \File::delete($filePath);
    }
}
```

When I run the same code on server, it works. Ia m assuming this is due to slashes. Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your path through `realpath()` which should clean up the mixed slashes and return a fully qualified path.

According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php):

```
echo realpath('/windows/system32');
```

would return

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32
```

So try running

```
$path = public_path(). '/Images/';
$this->MakeDirectory(realpath($path));
```

Comment: I tried this: `$path = realpath(public_path());      dd($path);` and it returns **C:\xampp\htdocs\My\Learning\admin\public** and when i try this: `$path = realpath(public_path() . '/Images'); dd($path);` it returns false !!!!

Comment: If realpath() returns false, it means that your path does not exist.  Try using it in your MakeDirectory() call as well.